# Duplicates php function

Tags: php, mysql, database, function, codeigniter

I'm having problem with my code. It always duplicate the input. Here's my function:

```
public function insert()
    {           
        $con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","dbms_project");
        if (!$con)
          {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }
        $sql="INSERT INTO customers (First_Name,Last_Name,Address,Phone)
                VALUES
        ('{$_POST['first_name']}','{$_POST['last_name']}','{$_POST['address']}','{$_POST['phone']}')";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
          {

          //redirect('home/customer');

          }
          $this->load->view('customer_view');
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
```

Here's the code in website. I'm also trying to store the next value to use it as a value for customer_id:

```
             //using insert function
             <form action ="<?= site_url('home/insert')?>" class="formInsert" method="post">
             <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Login">+</button></td>
             <td>
             //i'm trying to put the output and use it to be the value of the customer id
             <?php $con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","dbms_project");
                // Check connection
                    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                    {
                    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                    }
                $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT max(Customer_ID) FROM customers");
                $lastvalue = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
                $resultlastvalue = $lastvalue[0] + 1;
                echo  " ". $resultlastvalue . " " ;?>
                </td>
             <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required maxlength="40" autofocus /></td>
             <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required maxlength="40" autofocus /></td>          
             <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Address" required maxlength="40" autofocus /></td>          
             <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" required maxlength="40" autofocus /></td>          
             </form>
```

Every time I refresh the page it duplicates the duplicated value.

Comment: *"It always duplicate the input."* - which one? Plus, you're mixing MySQL APIs with `mysql_error()`. *"Everytime I refresh the page it duplicates the duplicated value!"* - Err... I don't get it. Duplicates in output or input in DB?

Comment: I was about to edit it. Anyway, everytime I refresh it with this link http://localhost/ci_intro/home/insert it duplicates more.

Comment: Duplicates how? It inserts duplicates entries in the database?

Comment: you are executing `mysql_query($sql, $con)` twice. First to insert and then inside the condition of the `if`. It is normal that you have duplicated records.

Comment: Set a unique constraint on the affected column(s).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will always insert duplicate records on page refresh. You need to change the logic a bit.

1. Take first name, last name and phone in 3 variables
2. Connect to database
3. Do a check if those exists using a SELECT query
4. If yes, don't run the INSERT query
5. If no, INSERT

We need to have something like this

```
$select = " SELECT * FROM customers WHERE First_Name = '$_POST['first_name']' AND Last_Name = '$_POST['last_name']' AND Phone = '$_POST['phone']' ";
 $query = mysqli_query($select);

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

                echo "User already exists";
                                  }
    else {
        $sql="INSERT INTO customers (First_Name,Last_Name,Address,Phone)
            VALUES ('{$_POST['first_name']}','{$_POST['last_name']}','{$_POST['address']}','{$_POST['phone']}')";
         }
```

Comment: `'$_POST['first_name']'` etc. will produce an syntax error. It should be like OP has it now `'{$_POST['first_name']}'`etc.  and as you have it below in the INSERT. However, using this method is open to SQL injection.

Comment: we just provided the logic (check before insert) . Are you expecting to write the entire code for you ?

Comment: This isn't "my" question. I'm the one trying to help and improve the answer. Which right now, won't work.

Comment: @Fred . Thanks for voting us down without any reason. Just imagine if we do the  same with your answers too.

Comment: How do you know that's my downvote? Which it isn't, so don't say that. Take that back. I'm not the only guy here. I even told you what to do to fix it and someone else saw your answer. See the upvotes on my comments? I can't upvote my own comments.

Comment: I'll even prove it's not my dv. Watch this.... see? now it's gone but the one who did downvote, is still there.

Comment: my dv............. edit dv removed. So take that accusation back. I'm expecting an apology.

Comment: and fix your answer or I **will** downvote it, then you'll see -2 instead of -1. **It's wrong,** it will **NOT** work as I originally stated. That's why the person who saw your answer, downvoted it. So, take it up with them, whoever it may be. **I'm still expecting an apology.** Plus, when I vote down *bad/incorrect* answers, I always tell them why.

Comment: Here, had you tested your answer (as I did), would have produced `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)` - there's my reason. Are you satisfied now?

Comment: Hi thank you for this! I tried it and this line mysqli_num_rows($query) wont work unless if this is the line mysqli_fetch_row($query)